# How to maximise performance in computers connected into LAN via Gigabit ethernet router?

Tags: router, switch, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Our group is setting up a server (which might just be a NAS, but we're not sure yet), which shares files, so that it connects to all other computers in the room (about 10 of them). I am thinking just hooking all of them up via a gigabit router/switch. Is there anything I should watch out for, in terms of cables, connections, or the connection capabilities of each computer in the network?
For instance, I don't want a slow computer in the LAN to slow down everyone else's connection, etc., etc.
Thanks for the education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you switch and server are GiGE and then other computers can't affect each other. I would also look to see if it has >1 LAN port to spread the load via teaming or even just clients 1-5 use .10 and 6-10 use .11. Make sure you use at minimum a cat5e or for very long runs cat6. I think you'll run out of disk I/O before you exhaust your network bandwidth.
I am not even sure a gig hub is made buy make sure you a switch and not a HUB.

Comment: Sorry, what's GiGE?

Comment: GigE is fancy for Gigabit ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to play with or check your jumbo packet size on each NIC driver and your switch.

Comment: Forgot to mention that +1

Comment: It's nice to get the opportunity & reward :-)

Answer (score 1):

Performance of the router specified in its description. For the switch performance can be considered as limited port capacity.